# VBA: Populating ListBox ActiveX control, on worksheet and not user form

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, listbox-control

I'm trying to populate a List Box (ActiveX control). This list box is on a sheet labeled "Dashboard" of my workbook, and not a user form. I want to populate it with a range from a sheet labeled "Data".

My problem is that if I populate it on the workbook open event procedure, I get an error when the workbook opens that it "Can't execute in break mode." However, there aren't breakpoints active at all.

If I populate it on the "Dashboard" worksheet active event procedure, it won't populate when the workbook is open. It only populates if I click on another worksheet, and then go back to the Dashboard worksheet, then it will populate.

Is there a better way to populate the list box so that it's always populated and ready to go? I have a lot of vLookup functions that are associated with the list box, and if the list box is not populated, then the rest of my code won't work.

I will post my codes that I have so far. The first is when I attempt to populate the listbox through the workbook_open even procedure. The second is through the "Dashboard" worksheet activate procedure.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim strName As String
Dim blDone As Boolean
Dim cPlanets As MSForms.ListBox
Dim vArray As Variant
Dim shtData As Worksheet
Dim wkbSolarSystem As Workbook
Set wkbSolarSystem = Application.Workbooks("workbookname.xlsm")
Set shtData = wkbSolarSystem.Worksheets("Data")
Set cPlanets = wkbSolarSystem.Worksheets("Dashboard").lstPlanets

vArray = shtData.Range("Planets").value
cPlanets.List = vArray
cPlanets.ListIndex = 3


'input box message for user when workbook opens up
strName = InputBox("Hello! Please enter your name", "Welcome!")

'check if there is a name entered via loop and if statement
Do
    If Len(strName) = 0 Then
        'if no name entered, ask user again
        MsgBox ("Please enter a valid name to continue"), vbCritical, "Valid Name Required"
        'ask user to type in name again
        strName = InputBox("Hello! Please enter your name", "Welcome!")
    Else
        'display message with information for user
        MsgBox ("Hello, " & strName)
        blDone = True
    End If
'finish loop statement
Loop Until blDone = True
```

This next code is the one I have on Sheet3 code worksheet activate procedure

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim shtData As Worksheet
Dim wkbSolarSystem As Workbook
Set wkbSolarSystem = Application.Workbooks("workbookname.xlsm")
Set shtData = wkbSolarSystem.Worksheets("Data")

lstPlanets.List = shtData.Range("Planets").value
lstPlanets.ListIndex = 3


End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried to make a public function on the Dashboard sheet, which fills the list, and call this function on Workbook_Open() ?

Comment: I tried this as well, but it still won't populate when the workbook is opened. Public Function addListsWorksheetActivate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code on a different computer, and it works. It seems that it's the computer configuration that was causing the issue. The code works fine as it should on several different computers.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring cPlanets as MSForms.ListBox, but in your question you say you are working with an ActiveX listbox on a sheet. So you should declare cPlanets as an Object, like:

```
Dim cPlanets As Object
Set cPlanets = wkbSolarSystem.Worksheets("Dashboard").lstPlanets
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to your suggestion now. However, it still won't populate it if I type that in the workbook_open procedure, because it errors out thinking it's on breakmode when it opens, but there aren't any lines of code on breakmode.